# GWT DialogBox - sizing problem when animation is enabled

Tags: gwt

GWT client code:

```
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
dialog.setAnimationEnabled(true);
SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel();
panel.setPixelSize(800, 600);
dialog.setWidget(panel);
dialog.center();
```

with the above code  the width of the dialog is not set properly - the dialog is cut off at about 400 px.

Without animation enabled it works ok, like in the code fragment below:

```
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel();
panel.setPixelSize(800, 600);
dialog.setWidget(panel);
dialog.center();
```

GWT ver 2.04
Firefox: 3.6.9
Chrome: 6.0.472.55 beta

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Fire up Firebug (or a similar tool) and check for yourself what the differences are :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some known bugs with DialogBoxes and sizing.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4597
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2595
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1424

There is a workaround which suggest to set the width on the gwt-DialogBox style.